# Regular Expression for atleast one character and one number with no repeat more than two

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, regex

I am trying one of regular expression for condition like:

atleast 1 number,
atleast 1 character,
should be 3 to 16 digit long. 
No character and number should repeat more than 2 time.

I tried one regular expression here what i tried.

```
(^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{3,16}$)\1{2,}
```

but it did not do the trick.

example for valid and invalid post:

- advan@123 -valid
- advan@4 -valid
- advvvan@123 -invalid
- advan@11123   -invalid
- advan123 -valid
- 1231123123ab -valid
- advadvvadv12 -valid

Comment: post some valid and invalid examples.

Comment: Your final solution should not be limited to regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using this regex (**edited** to fail strings that have triple consecutive symbols):

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?!.*(.)\1\1.*).{3,16}$
```

See [example here](https://regex101.com/r/vZ0uZ0/5).

Comment: yah, you edited.. simple one `^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?!.*?(.)(?:.*?\1){2})[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,16}$`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Thank you for the hint. Yes, a dot is enough since we already set the conditions in the look-aheads.

Comment: no, not inside the lookaheads . We defined it here `[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,16}$` . And the `.*` at the last inside the negative lookahead is unnecessary.

Comment: @stribizhev: thank you, the regex you provide it only take alphanumeric. It should validate the string which have atleast 1 character , atleast 1 number and no repeating character.

Comment: @HarishVirodhia: I updated the answer. It can now accept `3e3e%r4dfjhymsnw`. I hope it works now as expected.

Comment: @stribizhev it got failed for string like 3e3e3ee@12e. it count every instance of a character while it should be conscecutive repeat only

Comment: Updated. Now, `3e3e3ee@12e` passes, and `3e3e3eee@2e` fails. The only change is that I removed optional characters between `(.)\1\1`  inside the 3rd lookaround. Double consecutive symbols are allowed, as you see.